# Could not find default TaskScheduler bean -"scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor "

Tags: java, spring, tomcat8, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to use tomcat 8.0.36 in spring tool suite (sts) 3.6 version with spring 4 configuration. Server starts successfully but below error throws while starting.

```
DEBUG (localhost-startStop-1 ) [scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] Could not find default TaskScheduler bean
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler] is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:369)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:332)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.finishRegistration(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:192)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:171)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:86)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)


DEBUG (localhost-startStop-1 ) [scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] Could not find default ScheduledExecutorService bean
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler] is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:372)
```

Can some one address this issue? Thanks

Comment: Is it a maven or gradle project? I'm thinking classpath issue... if its a gradle project, gradle eclipse tooling does tend to 'polute' a project's classpath.

Comment: Its a maven project and maven version is 3.0.4

Comment: @Kris http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431776/using-scheduled-and-enablescheduling-but-gives-nosuchbeandefinitionexception. Here they gave how to hide error from logs but not actual fix for annotation based where as they gave fix for xml way.

Comment: you need to post some code